# Initializing a vector with a priorityqueue

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, priority-queue

I have found code similar to the following in a book about algorithms.  The code attempts to initialize a vector from the current state of a max_heap.  However, the following code in Xcode (7.3) yields the compile-time error:

> No Matching Constructor for initialization of 'vector'

```
// declaring priority queue
priority_queue<Star, vector<Star>> max_heap;


// pushing/popping to/from heap

// initializing vector with heap
vector<Star> closestStars(max_heap);
```

Either the book is in error or I am doing something incorrectly.  In the former case, is there a correct way to initialize a vector from the underlying container of an STL priority queue?

Answer (score 3):

The book probably assumes that `priority_queue` is a subclass of `std::vector`.

The C++ standard does not guarantee that.

Once constructed, `priority_queue` provides no `public` access to the underlying container, hence you cannot initialize a `std::vector` from it.

However, what you can do, apparently, is to subclass your `std::priority_queue`, with the subclass apparently having access to the inherited `protected` member `c`, which should be the underlying `std::vector`, that you can use to copy-construct another vector.